# Conditional string concatenation in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, null, string, condition, concat

I have a table `parcels` which currently contains the columns `owner_addr1`, `owner_addr2`, `owner_addr3`. Sometimes, one or both of the latter two fields is empty. I want to combine them into a single new field, `owner_addr` where each of the above fields is concatenated with `//` between each of them.

But if one or more of the original columns is NULL, I don't want to concatenate `//` to the result column. So for instance, if `owner_addr1` is `123 4th Avenue SE` and `owner_addr2` and `owner_addr3` are `NULL`, then I want the result column to just be `123 4th Avenue SE`, not `123 4th Avenue SE // //` (which would happen if I just did `CONCAT()` with `//` between the NULL strings ... I only want to add `//` between non-`NULL` columns, or leave it out altogether if there is only one non-`NULL` column.

Is there an easy way to do this kind of conditional concatenation in Postgresql, where it leaves out empty lines? Or should I write a python script to do this?

Comment: Related answer that may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12310986/939860. Note the last part about `concat_ws()` (and `concat()`) having function volatility `STABLE` (not `IMMUTABLE`), which prohibits their direct use in expression indexes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The function [`concat_ws()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) does exactly what you want. The first parameter is used as glue between the rest. Nulls are ignored:

```
select concat_ws('//', owner_addr1, owner_addr2, owner_addr3)
```

Test:

```
red=# select concat_ws('//', 'abc', null, null, 'xx', null, 'xyz', null) 
          as address;
   address    
--------------
 abc//xx//xyz
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably most obvious to use a CASE statement. There are 4 cases:

```
owner_addr2 IS NULL AND owner_addr3 IS NULL => ''       
owner_addr2 IS NULL AND owner_addr3 IS NOT NULL => '//' || owner_addr3
owner_addr2 IS NOT NULL AND owner_addr3 IS NULL => '//' || owner_addr2
owner_addr2 IS NOT NULL AND owner_addr3 IS NOT NULL '//' || owner_addr2 || '//' owner_addr3

SELECT owner_addr1 
    || CASE WHEN owner_addr2 IS NULL AND owner_addr3 IS NULL
            THEN ''
            WHEN owner_addr2 IS NULL AND owner_addr3 IS NOT NULL
            THEN '//' || owner_addr3
            WHEN owner_addr2 IS NOT NULL AND owner_addr3 IS NULL 
            THEN '//' || owner_addr2   
            WHEN owner_addr2 IS NOT NULL AND owner_addr3 IS NOT NULL 
            THEN '//' || owner_addr2 || '//' || owner_addr3
       END AS owner_addr
FROM ...
```

An alternative is to use 2 CASE statements:

```
SELECT owner_addr1 
    || CASE WHEN owner_addr2 IS NULL 
            THEN '' 
            ELSE '//' || owner_addr2
       END
    || CASE WHEN owner_addr3 IS NULL 
            THEN '' 
            ELSE '//' || owner_addr3
       END as owner_addr
FROM ...
```

COALESCE can be used instead of CASE:

```
SELECT owner_addr1 
    || COALESCE('//' || owner_addr2, '')
    || COALESCE('//' || owner_addr3, '') as owner_addr
FROM ...
```

Comment: Note that the answer assumes that `owner_addr1` is not null (the question seems to imply that, so it should be ok).

Comment: Yes, I assumed that. Gets more complicated if that is not the case. CONCAT_WS looks like a neat function, reminds me of LISP:-)

Comment: the coalesce form can be used the three terms the same and then a substring chopping of the start